# Transfer ethers from a smart contract to another smart contract in Truffle

Tags: solidity, truffle, ether

I am beginner in Solidity, So my problem may be simple. I have two contracts "BankA" and "customer". Whenever i deploy BankA in Truffle development environment and call `pay()` the following Error will emerge:

```
Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert    at PromiEvent (C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\contract\lib\promievent.js:9:1)
```

What is the solution. Thank you.

BankA:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.12;

import "./customer.sol";
contract BankA{
  function pay() public returns(uint256){
    customer client=new customer();
    address(client).transfer(1000);
    return address(client).balance;
  }
  function() external payable{}
```

}

customer:

```
pragma solidity^0.5.12;
contract customer{
  function() external payable{}
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the point of this contract? Cause by calling `pay()` you create a new contract of type costumer and try sending it 1000 wei. Although, contract BankA has no balance. We need more information to help.

Comment: if you add a fallback function (function to transfer funds to BankA), it will have funds later to transfer to contract customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though it should work provided BankA has sufficient funds.

Keep in mind that this:

```
address(client).transfer(1000);
```

cannot work if it doesn't have sufficient funds to send 1000 to client.

Therefore, either invoke with `{value: 1000}` (or more), or use the fallback for a sinple transfer of some funds to BankA. Otherwise, it will fail for insufficient funds.

Hope it helps.

p.s. Consider `address(client).transfer(msg.value);` to forward whatever was received.

Answer (score 1):

When we see, both contracts have fallback function. So, they can receive and send some ether in the platform. As @Rob Hitchens answered the error comes from the balance value of BankA. BankA never can send ether more than its balance. To make your code smarter about this problem, i suggest the followed code that can tell you about BankA's balance:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.12;

import "./customer.sol";
contract BankA{
  function pay() public returns(uint256){
    require(address(this).balance>1000, "Balance Not Enough");
    customer client=new customer();
    address(client).transfer(1000);
    return address(client).balance;
  }
  function() external payable{}
}
```